# UNIT TEST: queryForObject method not fully covered the lines

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock queryForObject method using Mockito. Unit test actually is passed but the lines is not fully covered.

The code to get the people object is like below:

```java
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_PEOPLE,
        (rs, rowNum) -> new People()
                .setId(rs.getInt("id"))
                .setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"))
                .setLastName(rs.getString("last_name")),
        department, position);
```

FYI: `GET_PEOPLE` is a static constant contain the SQL query.

and the unit test is:

```java
People people = new People();
people.setId(1);
people.setFirstName("John");
people.setLastName("Doe");

when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any(), (RowMapper<Object>) any(), any())).thenReturn(people);
```

Can anyone let me know how to mock to get the lines fully covered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which lines are not covered and which lines are covered? How do you inject your mock into your SUT and what is your test? How do you call your method under test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting coverage because you never execute that code.

You need to call your rowmapper:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Mock
    ResultSet resultSet;


    @Test
    public void myTest() throws SQLException {
        when(resultSet.getInt(1)).thenReturn(1);
        ...

        when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any(), (RowMapper<People>) any(), any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<People>() {
            @Override
            public People answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                RowMapper<People> rowMapper = invocationOnMock.getArgument(1);
                return rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, 1);
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```